# Delete data from the database while clicking an action in sweet alert

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sweetalert, onclientclick, commandargument

Basically, I am trying to create a sweetalert delete action while we click on delete(link button) inside GridView. While I'm clicking Delete Option on Sweetalert the record is not deleting.

This is my .aspx code

```
<asp:LinkButton OnClientClick="return deletealert(this);" ID="LinkButton2" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("EmployeeId")%>' runat="server" CommandName="CmdDelete" Text="Delete"  />
```

Here's my Code Behind Fired Method

```
protected void `gvEmployeeDetails_RowCommand`(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "CmdEdit")
            {
                Response.Redirect("EmployeeRegistration.aspx?ItemId=" + e.CommandArgument);
            }
            else if (e.CommandName == "CmdDelete")
            {
                int EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                obj.Remove(EmployeeId);
                GetData();
            }
        }
```

This is the JavaScript Code

```
    function deletealert(ctl) {
            // STORE HREF ATTRIBUTE OF LINK CTL (THIS) BUTTON
            var defaultAction = $(ctl).prop("href");
            // CANCEL DEFAULT LINK BEHAVIOUR
            event.preventDefault();
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary   file!",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: false
            }, function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
                    // RESUME THE DEFAULT LINK ACTION
                    eval(defaultAction);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe ", "error");
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

[Here's my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt68p.png)